# Could not derive which predicate may be called

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming

I'm studying for an exam and got stuck on one of the prep questions:

Question:

> The following Prolog-program is a meta-program. Explain why this
> program is a meta-program and give the output to the three questions
> to the program:

```
?- prove(moving_method(bird,M),N). 
?- prove(moving_method(ross,M),N).
?- prove(moving_method(kim,M),N).
```

I'm trying to run the code(on swish.swi-prolog.org) but it only gives me this error message:

```
Sandbox restriction! 
Could not derive which predicate may be called from
      call(C)
      prove(A,B)
      prove(moving_method(bird,A),B)
```

**The code we are given:**

```
:- dynamic moving_method/2, is_a/2.

is_a(bird,animal).
is_a(ross,albatross).
is_a(kim,kiwi).
is_a(albatross,bird).

moving_method(bird,fly).
moving_method(kiwi,walk).

prove(Fact,l):-
    Fact,!.
prove(Fact,X):-
    Fact=..[Rel,A1,A2],
    is_a(A1,SA),
    NewFact=..[Rel,SA,A2],
    prove(NewFact,X1),
    X is X1 + 1.
```

The error message might be fairly straight forward but how do I fix it? And why is this a meta-program?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this on your local machine with swi prolog? SWISH has a lot of functions turned off - I guess for savety issues.

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [sandbox.pl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/sandbox.pl)

Comment: As @DuDa notes, do not use SWISH for calls that are based on variables, e.g. `Fact`. Instead run it on a local install where the sandbox restrictions are not enforced.

Comment: Set it up on my computer and tried running it again which did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is this a meta-program?

See: SWI-Prolog [Meta-Call Predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metacall)

> Meta-call predicates are used to call terms constructed at run time.

In this case passing in the predicate to call, `Fact`, then running it as a goal.

Comment: Ok great, thank you!